# What subsystem should I use in VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm using VC++ 12 on Windows 8 and I want to make a C++ program that runs on Windows, OS X and Linux without any console or UI (user interface).

What subsystem**S** can I specify in `Properties > Linker > System` in order for my program do be able to run on Windows, OS X and Linux without any console or UI (user interface)?

I looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx and other topics but didn't find enough details.

Comment: Console, not surprisingly, means it allocates a console.  Windows means there's no console and you're generally meant to create a window but you don't have to.  Visual Studio isn't going to compile OS X and Linux versions for you.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Why not 'Extensible Firmware Interface' or 'NATIVE' or 'POSIX' ?

Comment: As the link you posted says, "NATIVE" and "POSIX" are for the long dead Windows NT and don't imply compatibility with any non-Windows system. I'm not aware of what EFI does though.

Answer (score 2):

The executable code will run on only one system. Either OS/X, Linux or Windows. But you can write your source in a portable way, so that you have only to compile it to run it on another platform.

If that is what you want, the best option is to use the console subsystem. Your program will have a normal main, and the standard io channels cout, cin, cerr (or stdout, stdin, stderr) and file descriptors 0,1 and 2 will also be standards. That way, I often have programs that run fine on Windows (compiled with MSVC), and compiles also without any modification with clang on gcc for Linux.

On the other hand, Windows subsystem is used to develop native Windows GUI heavily dependant on the Windows API.

Comment: What about 'Extensible Firmware Interface' ?

Comment: @Coding_King I never used anything else than CONSOLE and WINDOWS subsystems. AFAIK, NATIVE, BOOT, and EFI_* are only for special activities : drivers or boot.

Comment: EFI / UEFI have nothing to do with program code executed by an operating system.  If you are writing a boot loader to actually *load* an operating system (or something at that level, like a startup diagnostics interface) you might care about it.  If not, you might as well forget you ever read the term.